# GRPC Interceptor - Modify message by Number indicator's

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm learing  about grpc service in java and I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to intercept and modify a request.

I thought of modify the grpc request based on the number specified in the protobuf.

Sample Protobuf:

```
message PersonRequest {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  bool has_ponycopter = 3;
}

@Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall
            (ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
     // Get by number 1 (name from proto)
     // change the name
     // send the updated request

}
```

Is there any approach available to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the request message in the following server interceptor. Then your serviceImpl will receive the modified request message and process it.

```
import io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener;
...
 @Override
 public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
     ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers,
     ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> listener = next.startCall(call);
    return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(listener) {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
        ReqT modifiedMessage = modify(message);
        delegate().onMessage(modifiedMessage);
      }
    };
 }
```